# How to transfer a signal, which detects if the button is clicked or not?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like ask if it is possible to use Signal/Slot to transfer the information like: "is this button clicked?"

I prepared here some codes....

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtSlot(str, str, int, add_one_more_signal)
    def onJob(self, strA, strB, int1, add_one_more_signal):
        print(strA, strB, int1)

        # if the signal detects the btn1 was clicked:
        # print("button 1 is clicked; button 2 is not clicked")

        # if the signal detects the btn2 was clicked:
        # print("button 1 is not clicked; button 2 is clicked")



class MyApp(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str, str, int,  add_one_more_signal)
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("start 1", self)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("start 2", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def start(self):
        otherClass = Worker()
        self.signal.connect(otherClass.onJob)
        self.signal.emit("foo", "baz", 10, self.btn1.clicked(True) or self.btn2.clicked(True)) # How to write this line?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please dont understand me wrong. I know with my very rare knowledge how to achieve the programm purpose. I just want to know, how to transfer the Signal, which detects if the button is clicked or not. --To be honest, I also want to know the capability of Signal+Slot.

In my code there are two buttons. They share the same sub-function. (As I mentioned, just for this question.) When one of them is clicked, three parameters are transferred from MyApp-Class to Worker-Class.

Now I want to introduce a fourth parameter, which I also wrote in the code above. This fourth parameter does only one job, which is, to send the information, whether the button is clicked or not.

So my question is: If it is doable, how to write the code?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @eyllanesc With the fourth parameter there should be only one information transferred, as I can imagine. If this button is clicked, then the information should be something like: "This button is clicked."

Comment: @eyllanesc Or the information could also be like: "This signal comes from button 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to send the text that shows the button and for this the fourth parameter must be of type `str`, to obtain the object that emitted the signal we use `sender()`, in this case `sender()` will be the object that was pressed, then We get the text and we send it.

```
class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtSlot(str, str, int, str)
    def onJob(self, strA, strB, int1, text):
        print(strA, strB, int1)
        if text == "start 1":
            print("button 1 is clicked")
        elif text == "start 2":
            print("button 2 is clicked")


class MyApp(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str, str, int, str)
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("start 1", self)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("start 2", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def start(self):
        otherClass = Worker()
        btn = self.sender()
        self.signal.connect(otherClass.onJob)
        self.signal.emit("foo", "baz", 10, btn.text())
```

Comment: Thanks! But it cannot detect which button is clicked, because btn is actually not avaible.

Comment: @LucasMeier explain yourself better, which means that btn is not available, have you copied my code? I have tested it.

Comment: Sorry, I overseen a very import line. :-) Yes it works! Thank you so much!